# TMetaFileCanvas and DrawTextEx with DT_RIGHT flag and Arial font

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-xe3, drawtext

My program must use TMetaFile objects to draw text on a TImage. To do this i call system function "DrawTextEx".

When I assign the "Arial" font and right alignment (flag DT_RIGHT) the text is truncated at the end only if the string contains lots of  "1" chars (i.e.: "111111111111111112" string).

[image]

the white square is far smaller than the TImage canvas.

I've already posted a question about this topic but the answer didn't work with the TMetaFile.

Following the code to reproduce the issue:

```
procedure TForm2.test2click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  rc: TRect;
  s : string;
  oldBrushColor: TColor;
  OldBrushStyle: TBrushStyle;
  MetaCanvas: TMetaFileCanvas;
begin
  // in my example, image1 size is W:585, H:225
  MetaCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(Image1.Picture.Metafile, 0);

  rc := RECT(10, 10, 200, 200);

  oldBrushColor :=  MetaCanvas.Brush.Color;
  OldBrushStyle := MetaCanvas.Brush.style;

  MetaCanvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  MetaCanvas.Brush.style := bsSolid;

  MetaCanvas.Rectangle(RC.Left, RC.Top, RC.Right, RC.Bottom);

  MetaCanvas.Brush.Color := oldBrushColor;
  MetaCanvas.Brush.style := OldBrushStyle;
  MetaCanvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';

  MetaCanvas.Font.Height := 14;
  MetaCanvas.Brush.color := clwhite;
  MetaCanvas.Brush.style := bsClear;
  S := '111111111111111112'; 

  DrawTextEx(
    MetaCanvas.Handle,
    PChar(s),
    length(s),
    rc,
    DT_RIGHT,
    nil);

  MetaCanvas.Free;
end;
```

The problem is verified on Windows 7 and greater. Tested with delphi 2007 and XE3 version.